# ReactNative Xcode 14.2 unable to archive the builds

Tags: ios, react-native

I have tried to fix by using

export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider

still didn't worked

```
*/node_modules/metro/src/Bundler.js:58:29
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}
```

Comment: yes, tried with different release configurations it work.